# i'm using pycharm and whenever i run my code i continuously got this problem what can i do?

Tags: python

it's not interfere my program i can still run but it's constantly show up
this is the problem i got:
`c:\progra~1\common~1\system\symsrv.dll.000`
im using turkish language in image

```
Dizin adi ge�ersiz.
Erisim engellendi.
```

their translation :

```
The directory name is invalid.
Access Denied.
```

and this is the image of the problem:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwMSn.png

what can i do?

Comment: Have you tried to change to a different directory and then run it? This sounds like maybe a windows issue?

Comment: it doesn't matter what i wrote i'm always getting the same problem i even search on internet but i got nothing

Comment: run pycharm as admin.